# How to set jquery data in angular variable?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

[Please view this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVv0p.png)

```
    this.backendService.getadsettings().subscribe(settingsdata => {
          
          this.sdata=settingsdata;
          console.log("Settings Data")
          console.log(this.sdata)
        });

 var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container.adslider1', {
      

      autoplay: {
        delay: 5000,
      },

      // If we need pagination
      pagination: {
        el: '.adslider1 .swiper-pagination',
      },

      // And if we need scrollbar
      scrollbar: {
        el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
      },
    })
```

i want change this delay to dynamic. How to set that time in angular variable and how can i use that angular variable in delay ?

Comment: the only is put your code `var mySwiper=....` **into** subscribe function using `...autoplay:{delay:this.sdata[0].time},...`